# Error Message not showing up in the UI Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a hero and purposefully enter a number in the name so my validator in the backend catches it and throws the error. From the backend side of the things the error seems to be thrown just fine. I just can't get it to be displayed in the UI.

Hero-service.ts

```
public addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    console.log('Adding Hero');
    return this.httpClient.post<Hero>(baseUri + '/add', hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

handleError(error) {
    return throwError(error);
  }
```

hero-add.component.ts

```
error = false;
errorMessage = '';

//ngOnInit and other methods...

addHero(heroAddForm: NgForm): void {
    this.heroService.addHero(heroAddForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: Hero) => {
        heroAddForm.reset();
        this.goBack();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.defaultServiceErrorHandling(error);
      }
    );
  }

  vanishError() {
    this.error = false;
  }

private defaultServiceErrorHandling(error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    this.error = true;
    if (error.status === 0) {
      this.errorMessage = 'The backend seems not to be reachable';
    } else if (error.error.message === 'No message available') {
      this.errorMessage = error.error.error;
    } else {
      this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
    }
  }
```

horse-add.component.html

```
<body>

<div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Error! </strong> {{ errorMessage }}
  <button type="button" (click)="vanishError()" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>

<!... more html>

</body>
```

Comment: could you please give stackblitz of this code ?

Comment: What `console.log(error);` shows?

Comment: console shows error 422 statusText: OK and failure response for http....